# What is the complexity of $\Theta((n^3)/(\log(n))^4)$ ? Or $\Theta(n \cdot (\log(n))^3)$?

Tags: computational-complexity

What is the complexity of $\Theta\big(\frac{n^3}{\\(log(n))^4}\big)$ ? Or $\Theta\big(n \cdot (\log(n))^3\big)$?

Is the first one equal to $\Theta(n^3)$?

Comment: What does "complexity" mean in this context?

Comment: I mean can it be reduced to simpler form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these expressions can be simplified further.